# "no such file or directory" error during transfer in Automation Studio 4.12

Tags: error-handling, plc, br-automation-studio

When I want to transfer my program, I get an error. Everything worked before. I didn't change anything.

[image]

I tried to reinstall, install it on another computer.
Open a new project without anything — only with the program (ST program all in one).

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried running as Admin?